# "Overloading" GameObject?

Tags: unity, c#

I would like to show weapons and health items in an inventory grid.

The item can be rotated in the grid, and it occupies a certain region in the grid.

Currently I store this information (where the item is located, if it is rotated, etc.) in an additional array. However, this is not elegant and error prone.

I would therefore like to ask if it is possible to somehow store this additional information directly in the weapon or health GameObject.

Ideally I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
Pistol.GridProps.Rotation = 90
Pistol.GridProps.Row = 5
Pistol.GridProps.Col = 3
```

Is it possible to add something like "GridProps" to all my game objects?

Thank you!

Comment: You can use `GameObject.AddComponent` to add a script with these variables. Have you tried this? What didn't work?

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know this. I will try that.

Comment: @AlexF Works perfectly. Do you perhaps want to make your comment the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GameObject.AddComponent` to add a script with any variables you want.